# Trigonometry and finding max value

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to calculate $\max \{\sin(\alpha) + \cos(\alpha)\} $by JUST using the inequality between arithmetic and quadratic mean?

Assume that $ \alpha   $ is  $ [0, \pi/2] $

What about $\min \{\sin(\alpha) + \cos(\alpha)\}$ for $ \alpha   $ is  $ [0, \pi/2] $

Comment: What if we assume that sin and cos are in the first quadrant?

Comment: Try it and see...

Comment: The symmetry of the unit circle tells us the max lies in the first quadrant, so we can assume they're nonnegative. Using the inequality tells us the max is root(2) which happens at 45 degrees

Comment: what about the minimum value?

Comment: @fwd I think QM-AM holds for any real numbers

Comment: We observe that any positive value taken by the expression has a negative analog by a rotation of 180 degrees. Thus, the max and min cases are symmetrical and the min is simply -root(2)

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja yes, you're right, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = \sin \alpha, y = \cos \alpha$.

We have $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, so by AM-QM,

$$\frac{1}{2} |x + y| \leq \frac{|x| + |y|}{2} \leq \sqrt{\frac{x^2 + y^2}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}.$$

Therefore $-\sqrt{2} \leq x + y \leq \sqrt{2}$.

Equality is attained for $\alpha = \pi/4, 5\pi/4$.

For the minimum  on $[0,\pi/2]$,
$$1 = x^2 + y^2 \leq x^2 + y^2 + 2xy = (x + y)^2,$$
so $x + y \geq 1$. The minimum is attained for $\alpha = 0, \pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

We use this inequality:

$\frac 1n(a^m+b^m+ . . .)<\big(\frac{a+b+ . . }n\big)^m$

where a and b are positive numbers and m is positive  proper fraction. In interval you mentioned both $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are positive numbers, so we have:

$\frac12[(\sin^2 x)^{\frac 12} +(\cos^2 x)^{\frac 12} )<\big(\frac{\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x}2\big)^{\frac12}$

$A=\sin x+ \cos x<\sqrt 2$

Clearly $\sqrt 2$ can not be maximum of A that is maximum of $A=\sin x+\cos x$ can not be greater than  $\sqrt 2$ in interval $0<x<\frac{\pi}2$. Minimum of A is $\approx 1$ which is at $0+\epsilon$ or at $\frac{\pi}2-\epsilon$

Comment: thanks, what about min?